# Error : getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in loop

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

I'm doing a rss reader :

```
..
..
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');


  for ($i=$j=0; $i<=5; $i++) {




          $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
          ->item(0)->nodeValue;
..
..

}
```

I limit the number equals to 5, but some xml contain lesser than 5 item, so I get an error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object
```

I can do $ilength but I have to limit the numbers due to heavy load of images. How to resolve the error above?

Comment: So use an `and` check E.G:  `length and < 5`

Comment: @epascarello I have to limit the numbers otherwise the user have to download massive content.

Comment: I KNOW! Make the loop user the length and 5 as the cut off for the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based the loop off 5 and the number of items.

Not sure the syntax but with JS it would be

```
for ($i=$j=0; $i<=5 && $i<$x.length ; $i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=$j=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
 ..
 ..
 $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

 if ($xmlDoc->load($xml)) { // do the stuffs if file is loaded

   $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
   $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
   ->item(0)->nodeValue;
   ..
   ..
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
if(is_object($x->item($i))) { // check if the loaded item is object.
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: are you sure? it's not about the file, although I'm getting the error but I manage to see partial content. The error caused by the the missing tag when my $i is larger than available length.

Comment: btw, my instance should be outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your code to:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$ct = ( count($x)<=5 ) ? count($x) : 5;
for ($i=$j=0; $i<=$ct; $i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You want 5 as the maximum index:

```
$m = 5;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $m; $i++) { ...
```

But only if it is larger than the number of elements minus one within your result `$x`:

```
$m = min(5, $x->length);
```

See http://php.net/min for a more lengthier description of the handy `min()` function.

Next to that it's often much easier to use `foreach` and a [**LimitIterator**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) here:

```
$items   = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$limited = new LimitIterator(new IteratorIterator($items), 0, 5);
foreach ($limited as $item) {
    # ... just operate on $item ...
}
```

You won't have any invalid `$item` any longer inside the loop automatically. And your code might become more expressive, easier to read and to modify.